# Connecting MSAccess database with java webapplication

Tags: java, database-connection, ms-access-2013

I am trying to connect Msaccess database with my java webapplication using the following code:

```
    import java.sql.*;
 public class connection {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
// Load MS accces driver class
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  System.out.println("loaded");

  String url =  "jdbc:odbc:OnboardingTT";

   System.out.println("assigned");
  // specify url, username, pasword - make sure these are valid 
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");

   System.out.println("Connection Succesfull");

  } catch (Exception e) {
 System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());


    }}}
```

But connection is not established. and the error is

```
    loaded 
    assigned
  Got an exception!
    null   
    java.lang.NullPointerException      
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.initialize(Unknown Source) at
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source) at  
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at 
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at   
    connect.connection.main(connection.java:18)
```

I also tried with

```
 String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ="+ "C:\\OnboardingTT.mdb";
```

Is this code correct or i have to do any changes in this please answer my question

Comment: Can you show the full error you got using `e.printStackTrace(System.err)`, the information you currently print isn't useful

Comment: try by giving `e.printStackTrace()` in catch so that you will get to know what is the actual error..

Comment: Have you tried the url-only overload [DriverManager.getConnection(url)] instead of sending blank arguments?

Comment: `loaded
assigned
Got an exception! 
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at connect.connection.main(connection.java:18)`




complete error I am getting is displayed above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something went wrong with the DB connection, maybe the DB is not online, maybe the user or the password are incorrect...

Please provide more info to help us to help you.

;-)